Hodge dual of curvature two-form
I'm trying to compute curvature invariants on a general Kähler manifold $X$. One possibility is taking the norm $I$ of the Riemann curvature two-form $\mathcal{R}$ induced by the Hodge-structure^[1], as follows
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{R} = \mathcal{R}^a_{\,\,\overline{b} c \overline{d}} dz^c \wedge d\bar{z}^{\overline{d}} &\in \Omega^{1,1}(X)\otimes \text{End}(T_X) \\
\star\mathcal{R} &\in \Omega^{2,2}(X) \otimes \left(\text{End}(T_X)\right)^* \\
I := \left\langle \mathcal{R}, \mathcal{R} \right\rangle &= \int_X \mathcal{R} \wedge \star \mathcal{R}~.
\end{align*}
$$
The issue is that I'm not sure what the correct pairing of $\text{End}(V)$ with its dual looks like for a general bundle $V$ - is there a Hermitian structure we have to consider for this? Is it induced by the Hermitian structure on $V$? I suppose there is a natural pairing
$$ \text{End} V \otimes (\text{End} V)^* \simeq \text{End} V \otimes \text{End} V \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, \quad (A,B) \mapsto \text{Tr}(AB)~,$$
but am not sure if this is canonical. So the question, framed another way is: What is the inner product on $\text{End}(V)$?

[1]: I believe this is (the integral of) the "Chern-Pontryagin" class in $d=4$ real dimensions, but have not seen it used in $d \geq 4$.
